# generate json file from power bi report

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery

Is it possible to generate json file from power bi report?
and if it's possible how to make it?

i tried to make a function like that

(InputData) =>

let

`JsonOutput = Json.FromValue(InputData),`

`OutputText = Text.FromBinary(JsonOutput)`

in

`OutputText`

let

`Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Sales"]}[Content],`

`#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(`

`Source,`

`{{"Month", type text}, {"Sales", Int64.Type}}),`

`Output = GetJson(#"Changed Type")`

in

`Output`

in power query and its doesnt work with Cyrillic letters

or may be there is another ways to get json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open our PowerBI perort
2. Save it in dash_name.pbit(usuall dash_name.pbix)
3. Archives our report to .zip(!important!)
4. Open .zip file
5. Open report in .zip, open DataModelSchemas
6. We just got JSON